# How to: AJAX results from textbox from mysql

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

How to get my AJAX results from the input of a textbox populated from mysql live on the page.

I already got it to work with the use of textboxes, so if you check them then the page gets updated with the results of mysql.

The same I would like to use for my textboxes as soon as you type something in or select something from the autocomplete list (this would be even beter).

I have the following code that I want to use for the textbox:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" name="naam_klant" size="20" id="naam_klant" onkeyup="lookup(this.value);" onblur="fill();" >    
            <div class="suggestionsBox" id="suggestions" style="display: none;">
            <div class="suggestionList" id="autoSuggestionsList">
            </div>
            </div>
```

**PHP:**

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=records', 'root', '***');
$select = 'SELECT *';
$from = ' FROM overboekingen';
$where = ' WHERE FALSE';
$opts = isset($_POST['filterOpts'])? $_POST['filterOpts'] : array('');

if (in_array("naam_klant", $opts)){
$where .= " OR naam_klant = [$queryString%] ";
} 

$sql = $select . $from . $where;
$statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute();
$results = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$json = json_encode($results);
echo($json);
```

Comment: See http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: `$where .= " OR naam_klant = [$queryString%] ";` is wrong. Read about PDO and bound variables as fast as you can :-)

Comment: Probably wants `$where .= " OR naam_klant = '{$opts['naam_klant']}'";` but still should be done by binding...

Comment: @vogomatix can you explain whats wrong with it ? I know PDO is safer but for now I just want it to work first :)

Comment: @user3455717: see my second comment :-)

Comment: @vogomatix Thanks for your comment, I tryed your code but it does not show any results on the page.